# React app via `creact-react-app` not working

Tags: linux, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

How the issue produced:

1- using `create-react-app` i have created app

2- running `npm run start` it gave me the following error

[image: Error as shown in terminal]

Answer (score 0):

fixed using `sudo` => `sudo npm run start`

despite that the error didn't show any permissions issue to be figured at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have npm version 5.1 or earlier, you can't use npx. and for npm version npm 5.2+ and higher, use npx. 
And then install globally using following command:

npm install -g create-react-app

And then run application.

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app has problems with npm lastest version. I am using yarn package manager now for react and it's work very well https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install, it's really easy to install. install->retart terminal->and try it with "yarn start" command. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx` that comes with `npm` 5.2+.

Usage:

```
$ npx create-react-app
$ npm start
```